# How to manually verify fake video stream in chromedriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, webrtc

**What am I doing?**
I am trying to send a media file to my automated browser tests in place of real webcam footage

**Where did I try?**
I found this nugget of information of someone using it and passed in the same options as he did https://github.com/webrtc/samples/issues/616 .  So I've used the same options, different file formats (the y4m, mp4, mjpeg and other file formats), the path is an absolute file path on my mac.

**What do I see?**
When I navigate to sites like https://webcamtests.com/ to verify it, I see only my own camera showing my face.  I notice the camera name starts out as `videoinput#1` then switches to the name for my webcam.

**What do I think is the problem?**
I believe either the fake device isn't working, the virtual camera dies shortly after launch, or the file itself isn't be read.

**What would I like help with exactly?**
Has anyone here used the following chrome command line options?

```
--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=<filename>
--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=<filename>
--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
--use-fake-device-for-media-stream
```

I'm hoping to hear how folks used them and how they were able to manually verify they were working.

Answer (score 0):

root issue found, I was using the wrong file formats.

`use-file-for-fake-video-capture` supports .mjpeg file format

`use-file-for-fake-audio-capture` supports .wav file format

also, audio files are busted on a mac https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3287